# Mother's prayer with her small male child

Tags: salat, jamaat

My son is only six years old and he doesn't know his entire salat yet to lead is it permissible to let him stand with me while I pray? I have three other young daughters and we are usually lead by my husband but when he is away at work and it's just me is it ok to have him next to me since I can't lead him?

Comment: Please refer to this link: islamqa.info/en/9933

Answer (score 2):

Awuthubilamihiminashaytangnirajim Bisimillahirahmanirahim,

Sister Lateefa,

I consulted with a knowledgable Muslim brother with sound Aqidah and concluded below:

**Its fine for a boy to pray with mother at the condition that the boy is not of age for puberty.**

However, the **issue neither the brother nor I are clear on how to lead the prayer** in your scenario. Since women leading women are in the first row without stand out of it. Man leading will be standing in front of first row. They are the practice of our beloved Prophet Mohammad and diverse from Hadith and has been following since then, inshaAllah.

> You may want to ask the imam/Islamic scholar about:
>
> 1. How to lead when women leading children / kids without enter puberty.
> 2. How to lead when there is mixed gender female(enter puberty) + male (boy not in puberty)

So for now, you are aware that its ok to lead. While sometime, you can looking for a real knowledgeable scholar / imam for further instruction. Hope it helped, inshaAllah.

Answer (score -1):

Salam, I believe the brother is correct in his words. Since a female may not lead the salaat, perhaps letting the child know beforehand what he should be doing at what point in the salaat will be beneficial. Also (while you are not praying), you may ask him to pray while you watch, and let him know what he may correct after he is done with his salaat. This is how my mother taught me.
May Allah bless us.
Allah knows best.